# Is CPU frequency the only limiting factor for single threaded MySQL performance

Tags: mysql, innodb, single-threaded

I am running MySQL 5.7/InnoDB and want to optimize single-threaded select performance. The the database is mixing OLTP/OLAP queries and heavy OLAP queries frequently max out single cores for multiple seconds. I want to improve the time it takes for those heavy single-threaded queries to complete.

Assuming the application cannot be changed I am planning to upgrade the hardware. Currently MySQL is running in a VM on the following CPU:

`Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v2 @ 2.60GHz (Turbo @ 3.60GHz)` ([Intel Ark](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75269/intel-xeon-processor-e52650-v2-20m-cache-2-60-ghz.html))

I have an offer for the following CPU:

`Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4316 @ 2.20GHz (Turbo @ 3.60GHz)` ([Intel Ark](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/215270/intel-xeon-silver-4316-processor-30m-cache-2-30-ghz.html))

The new CPU is using more modern, using DDR4 instead of DDR3 RAM, but the base frequency is even lower. I am wondering if this CPU will make any improvement for MySQL single-threaded performance by just being more modern with faster memory?
My assumption is that it won't but I wanted to validate with the experts before. Thanks!

Comment: Test both configs and you will see. It is extremely difficult to judge a computer's performance theoretically.

Comment: Random accesses and possibly sequential too will probably be IO bound anyway so the speed of your storage device(s) may be more important.

Comment: next month 5.7 will reach end of life and no longer receive security updates; upgrade as soon as you can.

Comment: For your HEAVY query, EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (rest of your query); to find out where you have NO indexes that are CRITICAL for high-speed query completion.

Comment: High CPU usage usually implies poor indexes and/or poor formulation of queries.  Locate the naughty queries (and their tables) via the [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)